# asynchronous promise function

Tags: javascript, promise, buffer

I have an asynchronous method inside a class. It's purpose in life is to copy a buffer into another buffer starting from a given index. It's functionally identical to the Buffer.copy() method, except from one thing: It's wrapped in a promise.

```
    async _copyBuffer(from, to, index) {
        return new Promise((res, rej)=>{
            let ret;
            try {
                ret = from.copy(to, index);
            } catch(err) {
                console.error(err);
                rej(false);
            } finally {
                res(ret);
            }
        });
    }
```

It works, and I can await the copy in tests. My question is whether or not this is the right way to attack the problem, or whether this can be improved?

The reason I'm doing it this way is because I'm keeping track of the index extraneous to the function, and I'd like to ensure that things are copied in the right place at the right time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: why make a function `async` if you never need to `await` - makes no sense - other than that , since there's nothing asynchronous happening inside the promise executor, the whole thing makes even less sense :p

Comment: is `from.copy` synchronous? If yes, then wrapping it in promise is not needed; it won't make `from.copy` asynchronous.

Comment: 1. There is no need to use the Promise constructor in an async function/method. Async functions/methods already return a promise implicitly. 2. There is no reason for this to be async. `Buffer.copy()` is synchronous, so this doesn't do anything much. Just wraps the result in a redundant promise.

Comment: I do call it using `await`, but I really wasn't sure whether I'm just wasting my time or not. From the looks of it, it appears like I might be :)

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'll remove it from the async function, and remove the promise entirely.

Comment: "*I do call it using await*" but you don't have `await` inside the function. A ***MAJOR*** reason to use an async function is to use `await` inside it. If you don't, then *very likely* you don't need it to be async.

Comment: yes, you await a promise - but you don't have to make a function async if you return a Promise

Comment: I was under the impression a promise return was required inside an async function... always thought it was a little weird! Thank you for taking the time to explain this